# How to get my variable in another function in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

Here is my code

```
def main():
    getNumber()
    recursive(x)


def getNumber():
    x = int(input("Enter a number for 'x': "))
    return x



def recursive(x):
    print (x)




main()
```

Let's say I enter a number for 'x' in the getNumber function. That same number won't be printed on the recursive function. What is the problem?

After that, I need to make a recursive multiplication function but that will be for another day. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

`x` is  a local variable inside of `getNumber`, so when you call `recursive(x)`, it doesn't know what `x` is.

Instead,

- set `x = getNumber()` then pass it in

or

- pass it in directly like `recursive(getNumber())`

Comment: @GregEads If this answer helped you, please mark it the "best answer" by clicking the grey checkmark under the voting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to code

```
   x = getNumber()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your function to equal a variable to catch the return statement:

```
def main():
    x = getNumber()
    recursive(x)
```

`getNumber()` simply allows the `main()` method to access that variable once it is done. It is up to you to properly "catch" that variable and use it.

Think of it as though the text "getNumber()" is replaced with whatever the variable you are returning is. Does that clarify it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

This will work !!

```
def main():
    getNumber()
    recursive(x)


def getNumber():
    global x
    x = int(input("Enter a number for 'x': "))
    return x



def recursive(x):
    print (x)




main()
```

Comment: Visit http://thepythonguru.com/python-functions/ to learn more about global variables